# Drupal CCK-Views like features in another CMS with MSSQL (SQL Server) support

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, view, cck

I've been searching the CMS which could provide two most important features of Drupal (which is CCK and Views) and also support MSSQL (SQL Server, which my company runs its application).

Can anyone provide some suggestions (web-based, open-source or closed source, and php or non-php)? Although I prefer Open-Source PHP CMS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for data access to your mssql data, but are willing to run your cms on another db, give drupal a try with the forena report writing module.

Full disclosure: i am the author of forena.

Comment: What about the integration of mssql data access (forena) with CCK and Views?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm understanding, but forena can report (in the same report) data from mssql and mysql/postgres or whatever database you might need to connect to.  You just need some kind of common keys between the two systems.  It can certainly report on CCK data.  It doesn't yet entegrate with views.